# Watir Crawler is Stuck after Goto

Tags: ruby, selenium, watir, watir-webdriver, web-crawler

First time messing with Watir.

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new

browser.goto 'google.com'
```

My firefox window pops up and stays stuck on a blank page. When I end the script in the command line, I get:

`...ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.29.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/socket_poller.rb:95:in`sleep': Interrupt`

I've do have the `selenium-webdriver` gem (2.29) installed. My firefox version is 19.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not think selenium-webdriver supports Firefox 19. Try with Firefox 18.

Comment: This solution worked also for using selenium-webdriver 2.29 with cucumber and capybara. The error message was:
  `"unable to obtain stable firefox connection in 60 seconds (127.0.0.1:7055) (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError)"`

Comment: @MichalKováč: I think that capybara (just like watir-webdriver) uses selenium-webdriver to drive browsers, so this is actually the same problem, as you have already noticed.